# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions not invoked

Tags: android, permissions, request, runtime

I am checking permission using the following code. I always reach the part where shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is true. Then the Toast is shown but the permission dialog is not shown.

```
// checking permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS")
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS")) {
            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow the app to change the settings otherwise the app cannot change the brightness for you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"},
                    0);
        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"},
                    0);
        }
    }
```

Here's my app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appsbyusman.brightnesscontrol"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

In Manifest, I have declared the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

The app works fine in Lollipop device.
I am asking permission to change the system brightness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. We need to request permission to change settings in a different manner. We need to open an activity via intent and then the user will allow our app from there. Here's the code:

```
 // checking permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow the app to change the settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intentt = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                intentt.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
                intentt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intentt);
            } else {
                changeBrightness(extras); // it's android M and we have permission. Do permission related work here.
            }
        } else {
            changeBrightness(extras); // It's pre android M and we have got permission at install time. Do permission related work here
        }
```